# How to find "top" K from N numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

Need to be fast, does not need the top K to be EXACT: the top K is in the top 10%(for example) percentile is fine, or the majority of it is in top 10% percentile.

The N numbers are float, N can be as big as billions, K may be just tens of thousands.

Is there any existing algorithms that can do this? Preferably with a probability that can describe how the K number set in the top 10% percentile.

Comment: I assume a heap algorithm is too slow?

Comment: faster than a sort?

Comment: @btcgrl should be faster than a sort algo, ideally the time only depends on K not N.

Comment: The description of what you want is very vague.  Are you happy finding $K$ numbers that are (with some probability) within the top $10\%$?  There is a huge difference between finding the top $K$, which clearly involves looking at all $N$ numbers and finding $K$ numbers within the top $10\%$ because the top $10\%$ could be hundreds of millions.  It sounds like you have not thought clearly about what you want.

Comment: In simple words, I want to find K "relatively" big numbers from the massive set,  they do not need to be LARGEST, but the algo gonna be extremely fast (of course the bigger numbers the better).

Answer (score 2):

Let us first assume that we know the distribution of the $N$ numbers.  All we really need is the $90^{th}$ percentile point.  Once we have that, we can just look through the numbers until we find $K$ greater than that, which requires looking at $10K$ numbers on average.

Now the question comes down to taking a sample that finds the $90^{th}$ percentile point accurately enough for our purposes.  The simple answer is that takes (essentially) a constant number of samples, not growing with $K$ or $N$, so we don't care about it because for large $K,N$ the previous search will dominate.

A simple answer then is to look at a bunch of numbers and find the $95$ percentile point, then look through collecting numbers greater than that until you get $K$ of them.  This is linear in $K$.  Your collection will satisfy the request unless the measured $95^{th}$ percentile is in fact lower than the real $90^{th}$ percentile and you find a number between the two among your $K$ samples.